# SQLite INNER JOIN throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I can't understand why the query ends up throwing a `NullPointerException`.

My database contains two tables. The first one called `TABLE_WORDS` contains words; the second one called `TABLE_TRANS` contains the translations. One word can have many translations.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_WORDS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WORDS + 
    " (" + WORDS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + WORDS_WORD + 
    " TEXT);";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_TRANS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRANS + 
    " (" + TRANS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
    TRANS_WORD + " TEXT, " + 
    TRANS_FOREIGN_ID_WORD + " INTEGER, " +
    "FOREIGN KEY (" + TRANS_FOREIGN_ID_WORD + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_WORDS + "(" + WORDS_ID + "));";
```

I query translations by a word ID, and an `NPE` is thrown.

```
public Cursor queryTransesByWord(int idSend) {

    String query = "SELECT " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_WORD + ", " +
        DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + "." + DbHelper.TRANS_WORD + 
        " FROM " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + 
        " INNER JOIN " + DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + 
        " ON " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_ID + "=" + 
        DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + "." + DbHelper.TRANS_FOREIGN_ID_WORD + " WHERE " +
        DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_ID + "="+ idSend; 

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null); // NullPointer always throws here

    if (cur != null)
        cur.moveToFirst();
    else
        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, Constants.DB_ADAPTER_CLASS_NAME_SEP + "queryTransesByWord cursor is null");
    return cur;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, given your code:

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null); // NullPointer always throws here
```

That suggests that `db` is null. There's no other dereferencing operation in that statement - so unless the stack trace *actually* shows `rawQuery` in it somewhere, then `db` is null. You haven't given any indication of where `db` is meant to be assigned a non-null value, but that's the first thing to check...

As an aside, *please* don't include values in your SQL like that - it's a recipe for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Use parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: db wasn't null, I gorgot to open it before query.    public class DbAdapter {

 private DbHelper helper;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;
 private int openStatus;    public void openForReading() {
  if (openStatus == 0) {
   db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
   openStatus = 1;
  } // if (openStatus == 0) 
  else 
   if (openStatus == 2) {
    helper.close();
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
   } // nested if (openStatus == 2)
  
  Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, Constants.DB_ADAPTER_CLASS_NAME_SEP + "openForReading succeed"); 
 }

Comment: @RedPlanet: In that case, the line you showed wouldn't have been at the top of the stack trace. (This is why you should have included the stack trace in your question.) But it looks like if you haven't called `openForReading` then `db` *will* be null...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I should use

```
String query = "SELECT " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_WORD + ", " +
    DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + "." + DbHelper.TRANS_WORD + 
    " FROM " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + 
    " INNER JOIN " + DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + 
    " ON " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_ID + "=" + 
    DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + "." + DbHelper.TRANS_FOREIGN_ID_WORD + " WHERE " +
    DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_ID + "=?";    

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { Integer.toString(idSend) } );
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "SELECT " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_WORD + ", " +
DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + "." + DbHelper.TRANS_WORD + 
" FROM " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + 
" INNER JOIN " + DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + 
" ON " + DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_ID + "=" + 
DbHelper.TABLE_TRANS + "." + DbHelper.TRANS_FOREIGN_ID_WORD + " WHERE " +
DbHelper.TABLE_WORDS + "." + DbHelper.WORDS_ID + "=?";    

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { Integer.toString(idSend) } );
```

this works for me:-)